# How to add function call highlighting in ESS?

Tags: spacemacs, ess, r

I currently have some syntax highlighting in my ESS code (e.g., for brackets, `=`, and strings). I would like to add highlighting of function calls, like RStudio's "Highlight R function calls" option. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ess-R-font-lock-keywords` is a user option that is [mentioned in the ESS manual](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#index-ess_002dR_002dfont_002dlock_002dkeywords) as:

> Font-lock patterns for ESS R programming mode. (There is a corresponding ess-S-font-lock-keywords for S buffers.) The default value highlights function names, literals, assignments, source functions and reserved words.

Example configuration:

```
    (setq ess-R-font-lock-keywords
      '((ess-R-fl-keyword:keywords   . t)
        (ess-R-fl-keyword:constants  . t)
        (ess-R-fl-keyword:modifiers  . t)
        (ess-R-fl-keyword:fun-defs   . t)
        (ess-R-fl-keyword:assign-ops . t)
        (ess-R-fl-keyword:%op%       . t)
        (ess-fl-keyword:fun-calls    . t)
        (ess-fl-keyword:numbers)
        (ess-fl-keyword:operators . t)
        (ess-fl-keyword:delimiters)
        (ess-fl-keyword:=)
        (ess-R-fl-keyword:F&T)))
```

Setting `ess-fl-keyword:fun-calls` to `t` turns on function call highlighting.

I also found out from [a stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19624698/13945974) that these can also be set manually through the ESS > Font Lock submenu.

Comment: Could you elaborate, to make your Q&A more useful to others? Maybe explain why that change takes care of it?